# Binding to properties of Storyboard declared in UserControl

Tags: wpf, binding, storyboard

I'm struggling with a binding that only works when declared inside a Window's resources area. As soon as I move the declaration to a UserControl's resources area, the binding fails. No error message, but the value is not updated when the value of the slider (source) is changed. I would like to use the storyboard inside one of the UserControl's VSM states.

Can someone please tell me why this happens and hopefully how to fix it?

I tried pasting my xaml here, but the website doesn't seam to allow the xml tags in the message.

Regards

Jaco

Comment: I have figured out this much: The problem lies in the scope of the storyboard. It seams to be unable to find the control (slider) I'm refering to in the binding statement.

So why would it work for a Window, but not for a UserControl?

Answer (score 0):

Only set the Storyboard.TargetProperty (and not .Target or .TargetName) and point the storyboard to the object in code:

```
Dim SB as Storyboard = Me.FindResource("Storyboard_name_goes_here")
TargetObject.BeginStoryboard(SB, HandoffBehavior.Compose)
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes, this i a very good suggestion. However I would like to use the storyboard inside a VSM state. So I want the VSM to initiate the storyboard as a transition, not invoke it manually from code behind.